# Play! Framework 2.0.4 with JAVA and RabbitMQ integration

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.0, rabbitmq

I'm just beggining my development with Play! Framework 2 and I met problem related to integration with RabbitMQ. 
To start with I added proper line to Build.scala configuration file:

```
    val appDependencies = Seq(
       "com.rabbitmq" % "amqp-client" % "3.0.1"
    )
```

But now I'm still unable to import any of files from package com.rabbitmq.*;
When trying to refresh page it says:

> Compilation error
>
> error: package com.rabbitmq does not exist

What am I doing wrong? I use IntellJ IDE.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you reload the project by using "reload" in the Play console ?

Comment: Restarting IDE was everything required to make it work. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can also download dependencies by using "play eclipse" and refresh your eclipse project.